# Is my computer good enough?

Tags: memory, cpu, ramdisk

So I'm trying to run a game on my computer and it lags quite a lot. According to this page https://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri I can't run it, since it says that my CPU isn't good enough, and my RAM barely passes the minimum. My question is, obviously this game won't be played perfectly in my computer, but in case that I bought a better RAM, would I notice an important improvement? Is it worth it or should I just drop it? Could it cause any damage to my computer if I keep using this game without fulfilling the requirements to run it?

Comment: Drop it because it's a waste of time, not because it can damage the PC (it can't).

Comment: This is as vague and general as your question.  The video card is the number #1 determinate for video games. You should have 8gb of RAM, and most modern CPU won't cause your system to bottleneck.  That being said for all I know you could have Pentium 3 CPU, which definitely will bottleneck you.

Answer (score 2):

It won't damage your computer, it will just damage your game-play quality.

Without a full spec list of your computer, plus the recommended specifications of the game you will be playing, it's very hard to give an accurate answer.